# adb device doesn't listed on cmd {Lenovo K8 Plus}

Tags: adb, rooting, fastboot, boot-loop

I am trying to root my Lenovo K8 Plus after unlocking bootloader. I try to install TWRP and somehow the TWRP recovery doesn't open and the phone is struck in the bootloop.
I then fastboot the device and connect to PC and open minimal fastboot cmd. The phone wasn't listed in adb device, but listed in fastboot devices.

I think usb debugging is not turned on because the system doesn't restart (maybe there is no ROM).

What should I do?

Comment: don't mix up adb with fastboot

Comment: Hi, I try to make your post more clearer. This requires me to edit your sentences and add more words, which may not be your intention. Please check and see if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Common mistake these days people do not read the instructions.
Here is a example Warning from TWRP site:

> This device uses dm-verity!
>
> This means that swiping to allow system modifications will prevent you from being able to boot if you are using the stock kernel. In order to bypass dm-verity's boot prevention, you will have to install a kernel that has dm-verity disabled in the fstab.

Go back to the Tutorial where you have downloaded TWRP and read, i am pretty sure there is something you forgot to flash.
[Universal DM-Verity ForceEncrypt Disk Quota Disabler](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/universal-dm-verity-forceencrypt-t3817389)

Another common mistake after flashing TWRP you must not boot into android. Reboot straightforward into recovery right after flashing, otherwise your custom recovery will be replaced with stock recovery
`/system/recovery-from-boot.p`

Comment: Universal Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt.zip has issues with encryption, [no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt) is recommended instead