# Why does my twrp custom recovery not work?

Tags: recovery-mode

I've recently wanted to root my phone I unlocked the bootloader and followed a tutorial of how to add the twrp custom recovery I complete it and everything seems fine but when I turn on my custom recovery it just shows the android recovery

My phone is a allwiev p7_pro
I've used the recovery file from XDA developers

Comment: It is best if you list the instructions or at least link the tutorial which you followed.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214929

Comment: Keep in mind that do NOT boot into system after flashing TWRP. Take out the battery, insert it, and boot into recovery. If you don't have a removable battery, boot to recovery from fastboot/adb as soon as you finish flashing.