# xiaomi redmi note 4 stuck in bootloop after making twrp backup

Tags: boot-loop, xiaomi, redmi-note-4

attempt to flash lineage os los16 mido on xiaomi redmi note 4. unlocked bootloader and flashed twrp according to los mido official page instructions. made backup in twrp by checking all boxes.(system, vendor, data, cache, recovery, boot, persist, bootloader, firmware, efs). didn't make any other changes in options/encryption. total size came to 14gb+. after system reboot it got stuck in bootloop (mi logo, 'unlocked' written at bottom of the screen). on holding down power key it vibrates, and reboots back to mi logo. on holding vol up and power, boots into twrp. tried wipe>advanced>cache, dalvik and then also tried wipe>factory reset but to no avail. please please help me as i need my phone back asap for work. with the curfew idk when i'll be able to take it to a service centre until which time i'll be w/o a phone.

this is my first time so please excuse me if i've not followed/violated any rules and i'll make the changes. thanks

Comment: you flashed TWRP that is the change that prevent from boot https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902

Comment: just boot into twrp and install no-verity-opt-encrypt. If your phone is working again, backup boot, root with magisk, then backup with [Migrate](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-migrate-custom-rom-migration-tool-t3862763). save all backups to PC, restore boot, wipe system, install LineageOS and gapps. format userdata and reboot. for rooting install addonsu-16.0-arm64-signed.zip

Comment: https://www.thecustomdroid.com/install-magisk-root-android-devices/#Method-2-By-Flashing-Magisk-Patched-Boot-Image-using-Fastboot

Comment: https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/mido/install#installing-lineageos-from-recovery