# Lenovo Tab 4 10 stuck on boot after factory reset with TWRP

Tags: root-access, twrp, lenovo

I wanted to root my Lenovo Tab 4 10 tablet, so I installed TWRP successfully but then my internal storage was showing up 0 Mb. So I use OTG (Pendrive) to flash SuperSU zip. Then it was stuck on mounting, so I switched my tab off. Then I even factory reset my tab via TWRP and recovery mode. But now it is stuck on the boot logo and doesn't boot up no matter how many times I reboot or factory reset it.

I even tried flashing the stock firmware. Still got no good results

I don't have access to USB debugging or TWRP now.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902

Answer (score 0):

I had did this once on my Lenovo tab 4 10 So I installed the firmware of my tablet from here “https://firmwarefile.com/lenovo-tab-4-10-tb-x304l”
After downloading the firmware extract the files from the zip file and search for “recovery.img” in that folder and flash that recovery(your bootloader should be unlocked ) and then after that there will be system recovery installed on your device now go to fastboot and then to recovery mode and then reboot your device and you will see the Lenovo logo for atleast 2 mins and then your device is unlocked and then you can lock or keep the bootloader unlocked (I didn't use my PC I used this app called “Bugjaeger”