# Easiest way to root Xiaomi redmi 4x with TWRP

Tags: rooting, twrp, xiaomi

I'm trying to root my Xiaomi redmi 4x (Android 7) using TWRP.  I have unlocked the phone,   turned on USB debugging and odm.  It's my first time ever trying and seem to get confused following the instructions I have found on YouTube and Google.  Many seem to have skipped steps or are not very clear.  Can someone please help me with a step by step guide to rooting my phone and the links to download the required apps. I would greatly appreciate it since I have four days trying to figure it out.  My head hurts from it at this point.

Comment: If bootloader is unlocked, flash TWRP uisng `fastboot flash` and then from TWRP flash Magisk zip for rooting. What's the confusion?

Comment: [twrp-3.4.0-0-santoni.img](https://twrp.me/xiaomi/xiaomiredmi4x.html) + [no-verity-opt-encrypt-6.1.zip](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt) + [Magisk-v20.4.zip](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#download)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902