# Xiaomi android always boot in recovery (twrp) mode

Tags: twrp, fastboot, xiaomi, redmi

I tried to install twrp in my xiaomi redmi 7A, and it worked, but now i'm not able to boot the system.
The steps i followed are as follows:

1. fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
2. fastboot boot recovery.img

It seems like i have to flash the firmware, but i want to see another solutions for obvious reasons.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best solution is to flash the stock firmware. Or the other option is if you backed up recovery partition then you can flash it through twrp to go back to stock recovery, which can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Where can i download good/thrusty firmware image? I'm downloading from some site i found but i'm not secure about it.

Comment: https://xiaomistockrom.com/xiaomi-redmi-7                 Do upvote.

Comment: Due to the poor attention to this problem, i've check the @munsoft004 response as accepted. And yes, i did flash the firmware.

Comment: For future intent to flash TWRP with fastboot, if the command "fastboot flash recovery recovery.img" works, do not run fastboot boot recovery.img