# fastboot stuck on 'booting...'

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, custom-roms, fastboot, boot-loop

I am trying to flash my device(Redmi S2/Y2). I unlocked the bootloader and I tried flashing Orange Fox recovery from fastboot.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
target reported max download size of 534773760 bytes
erasing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.020s]
sending 'recovery' (38400 KB)...
OKAY [  0.925s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.189s]
finished. total time: 1.159s

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot boot recovery.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.879s]
booting...
```

It was stuck at `booting...` every time I tried. While trying some solutions, I messed up and now I am stuck at bootloop. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Are you sure the recovery image is compatible with the device, i.e. maybe model no. It goes to bootloop if you flash wrong files.

Comment: just keep holding Volume Up + Power until TWRP logo (recovery mode) is visible

Comment: regarding boot-loop https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902

Answer (score 1):

It worked out, it turned out to be a hardware problem that didn't let me use the Volume Up + Power Key for Recovery Mode.