# how can installing a custom recovery such as TWRP lead to a device going into a bootloop

Tags: twrp

I see a large number of posts stating that users ended up with their device going into a bootloop after flashing TWRP.

If TWRP is flashed to the /recovery/ partition, how is it possible for the device to go into a bootlop during a normal start up?

Comment: when altered a partition, that fails to pass the [dm-verity](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214902) sanity check

Comment: what relation does dm-verity have with android verified boot?

Comment: [dm-verity](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity) is verified boot (at runtime) while [AVB](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/avb) is verification of partitions (during flash or boot)

Comment: is there any relation between unlocking the bootloader and dm-verity or AVB?

Comment: that are three different pieces in the chain of trust, but it all goes hand in hand

Comment: so dm-verify needs to be disabled via adb first prior to installing a custom recovery or else the device will boot loop?

Comment: you can flash custom recovery and install disable_dm-verity.zip or no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip or magisk.zip to disable dm-verity. if AVB is problem for custom recovery, you can flash empty vbmeta.img to disable AVB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What creating bootloop when flashing TWRP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232375/what-creating-bootloop-when-flashing-twrp)