# Phone unresponsive after fastboot boot command

Tags: fastboot

I try to root a Xiaomi Redmi note 5. After issuing the command

```
fastboot boot twrp-3.4.0-0-vince.img
```

The screen turns black, with the Xiaomi logo at the center of the screen and 'Unlocked' is written at the bottom. I've tried several img versions, verified their names are correct(that is, they don't end with a double .img), as well as holding the Volume up and Power buttons, but the outcome was always the same.

My CMD:

```
C:\Users\Oagroup\Desktop\ADB>fastboot devices
380387a fastboot

C:\Users\Oagroup\Desktop\ADB>fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.4.0-0-vince.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (36804 KB)...
OKAY [  0.801s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.527s]
finished. total time: 1.330s

C:\Users\Oagroup\Desktop\ADB>fastboot boot twrp-3.4.0-0-vince.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.801s]
booting...
OKAY [  0.154s]
finished. total time: 0.959s

C:\Users\Oagroup\Desktop\ADB>fastboot oem device-info
...
(bootloader) Verity mode: true
(bootloader) Device unlocked: true
(bootloader) Device critical unlocked: true
(bootloader) Charger screen enabled: false
OKAY [  0.007s]
finished. total time: 0.010s
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902 the first command **flashed** TWRP, therefore you must disable dm-verity. i recommend OrangeFox Recovery because TWRP has [issues](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/1386) with disk quota

Comment: I don't understand the instructions in the link. What should I do after I download the zip? Should I flash it, and if so, how? (I am all new to this stuff).

Comment: [no-verity-opt-encrypt-6.1.zip](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt) can be installed from TWRP menu. please confirm your device is vince (not whyred, rosy, riva) flash TWRP from fastboot (again), then `fastboot reboot` (while keep holding Volume Up)

Comment: after flashing keep connected, press + hold Volume Up only (not Power), type *fastboot reboot* while holding Volume Up, release Button when you see TWRP splash screen