# Not booting into TWRP but instead stock recovery

Tags: samsung, twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-grand

I installed TWRP with ODIN and used `adb reboot bootloader` to go into Odin mode.
When I boot into recovery it goes to the stock recovery.
I used this command:- `adb reboot recovery` to go into recovery.
What went wrong?
I am using sm-g350h.

Comment: TWRP is not installed. after flashing you must not boot into android. flash again or install from TWRP app https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902

Comment: should I untick the auto reboot option?

Comment: yes untick the auto reboot option and use the buttons vol-up + home + power to enter recovery mode

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: install from TWRP app

Comment: What if my device is not rooted

Comment: get current stock ROM version from Frija or Samloader, install Magisk Manager, patch the AP\*.tar.md5 file, flash magisk_patched.tar as AP together with BL CP and CSC

Comment: How do I patch it?

Comment: patch with [Magisk Manager](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD). you can also root with [SuperSU](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu) it comes prepatched