# Phone keeps rebooting on Volume Up + Power (trying to install ROM)

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, boot-loop, installation, xiaomi-mi4

I tried to install Android's ROM and got **ERROR 7**, then I wiped out cache, data, internal storage, where was twrp.apk installed.
After that I cant get into boot menu (with Install, Wipe... buttons).
Then I copied **twrp** to the phone:
`sudo fastboot flash recovery <twrp.img>`
Tried versions **3.2.1-0** and **3.4.0-0**, because I heard for certain phone (I have Xiaomi Mi4) it's necessary to use proper version, though I don't know which.

What's going on now:
I can successfully can get to the nice splash screen using `Volume Down + Power`, then on my PC I give `sudo fastboot reboot` command and press `Volume Up + Power` and here is the problem: It has no effect, it just keeps rebooting (I see only Xiaomi's logo).

Comment: I would try to directly boot into recovery without flashing: `fastboot boot recovery <twrp.img>`.

Comment: @Robert `error: cannot load 'recovery': No such file or directory`. I did **Down+power**, then waited till fastboot picture appears on the screen and then executed your command with path to **twrp.img**.

Comment: Sorry my fault the `recovery` was too much. Just execute `fastboot boot <twrp.img>`.

Comment: @Robert FAILED (remote: dtb not found)

Comment: which chipset your Mi 4 have? MSM8939 (ferrari), MSM8974 (cancro), MSM8992 (libra)

Comment: @alecxs I made a search on my model 2014215 and it seems cancro.

Comment: flash official TWRP for Xiaomi Mi 3 and keep holding Volume Up while rebooting from fastboot. in TWRP disable [dm-verity](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902)

Comment: @alecxs I forgot about disabling dm-verity, now I have `powered by Android` booting. What does it mean if I have forgoit it?

Comment: @alecxs anyway, I've made it, it works. Thanks a lot. https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fthumbs.gfycat.com%2FFrailLeafyArcticduck-max-1mb.gif&f=1&nofb=1