# Boot to ROM recovery instead of TWRP

Tags: twrp

My phone is OnePlus 5t.

In fastboot mode I flashed TWRP
`fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.5.2_9-0.img`

and every time I try to enter recovery mode it just start the original recovery mode that came with the system.

But if i enter 'fastboot' and type:
`fastboot boot twrp-3.5.2_9-0.img`
the TWRP comes up....
How can I make it automatically TWRP? ty!

[image]

Edit: someone send me this: [adb device doesn't listed on cmd {Lenovo K8 Plus}](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214902/adb-device-doesnt-listed-on-cmd-lenovo-k8-plus)

And this was the problem:

`Another common mistake after flashing TWRP you must not boot into android. Reboot straightforward into recovery right after flashing, otherwise your custom recovery will be replaced with stock recovery /system/recovery-from-boot.p`

Comment: A lot of system ROMs automatically flash a built-in recovery ROM when you boot it. Therefore if you want to permanently stay at TWRP you have to identify where in your main ROM this happens and disable it.

Comment: How can I do it? I have no idea....

Comment: usually TWRP will figure it out itself when you swipe to allow modifications

Answer (score 1):

i think u need to flash 2 more files , called "force dm verification" and "decrypt" not sure that's the exact name but these basically get the job done

Comment: this can be useful for modifications. but will not solve the problem caused by *recovery-from-boot.p*