# twrp recovery installed but it boots to android instead

Tags: twrp, rom

i wanted to add custom rom to my galaxy j7 max and hence tried installing twrp(3.1.1& 3.2 or what ever) in Odin the task passed but then when i try to boot to it by pressing vol up+ power + home , instead of opening twrp it boot normally to the android and cannot get twrp .. so plz help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adb device doesn't listed on cmd {Lenovo K8 Plus}](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214902/adb-device-doesnt-listed-on-cmd-lenovo-k8-plus)

Comment: Read this: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-root-twrp-3-1-1-1-samsung-galaxy-j7-max-2017-sm-g615f.3710048/