# Bootloop after rebooting the system (Android 7)

Tags: twrp, 7.0-nougat, huawei

I have a TRT-LX2 phone, I recently performed a system update and after that my phone booted perfectly. But when I tried restart it again into recovery (I've installed TWRP before updating) it did not boot up and loops. Then I tried to boot it normally, it also loops!

After 12 attempts, the phone was booted into recovery and I restored the backup (which is the previous version of the system). But it still loops!

Finally I connected the phone with the PC and extracted the backup file but I did not see any boot image!

Can I recover my phone now? (Or, I've buy a new one?)

Comment: disable dm-verity

Comment: @alecxs How can I do that?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902