# Data partition corrupted TRT-LX2

Tags: boot, 7.0-nougat, emui, data

Please read [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241078/bootloop-after-rebooting-the-system-android-7) first!!!

I've disabled dm-verify and then it says the data partition is corrupted!

I did a low-level factory reset, but it is still showing that annoying message when I try to boot it up.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably destroyed encryption, this can happen if Universal DM-Verity ForceEncrypt Disk Quota Disabler is used without reading the instructions:

> The zipname tells the installer what to do. Here are the current options:

- Add 'enfec' to zipname to keep forceencrypt enabled if present

This may have caused mismatch between different fstabs. Either restore backup of boot + vendor, or fix fstabs manually, or flash stock ROM

Comment: Thanks, flashing stock ROM worked for me!