# How to install OS in Samsung smg531f which is without OS?

Tags: samsung, installation, 5.1-lollipop

I have a samsung SMG531f Grand Prime. I accidentially deleted my OS in Team Win by selecting the System option coming under Wipe option in the main menu. Now when I switch on the phone it will show only the startup screen. I can only go to the TeamWin by pressing Volume up Home and power button. But when I try to go to odin mode by clicking on volume down power and home button it doesn't work. How can I overcome this problem and reinstall os to this phone.

Volume up key doesn't work in this phone.

Prefer a solution which can be configured in Windows environment as I don't have access to an open source OS.

Comment: on newer samsung devices system.img is lz4 compressed. yours should be simg2img sparse image

Comment: @alecxs Could you elaborate on how can I do it step by step?

Comment: this is the origin of simg2img.exe but I recommend more recent version for linux https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1054836&page=3

Answer (score 1):

1. download and extract ROM from [samloader](https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy)

   ```
   cd /media/xubuntu/1234567890ABCDEF
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install android-sdk-ext4-utils android-sdk-libsparse-utils android-sdk-platform-tools-common android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot f2fs-tools git python3.8 python3-pip

   git clone https://github.com/nlscc/samloader

   cd samloader
   pip3 install .
   cd ..
   sudo cp -av ~/.local/bin/samloader /usr/local/bin

   mkdir Android
   cd Android

   samloader -m SM-G531F -r SLK checkupdate
   samloader -m SM-G531F -r SLK download -v G531FDDU1APJ2/G531FODD1APJ2/G531FDDU1APJ2/G531FDDU1APJ2 -O .
   samloader -m SM-G531F -r SLK decrypt -v G531FDDU1APJ2/G531FODD1APJ2/G531FDDU1APJ2/G531FDDU1APJ2 -V 4 -i SM-G531F_1_20161116150254_w0xdzpk60j_fac.zip.enc4 -o SM-G531F_1_20161116150254_w0xdzpk60j_fac.zip

   unzip SM-G531F*.zip
   tar -vxf AP_G531F*.tar*
   ```
2. convert [system.img](https://github.com/anestisb/android-simg2img) into mountable disk image

   ```
   mv -v system.img system.sparse.img
   file system.sparse.img
   simg2img system.sparse.img system.img
   file system.img
   ```

   (optional) check if mountable

   ```
   mkdir system
   sudo mount -vo loop,ro,noexec,noload,noatime -t ext4 system.img system
   ls -a system
   sudo umount -v system
   ```
3. copy file to MicroSD Card

   ```
   adb push system.img /external_sd
   ```

   (optional) compare digest

   ```
   md5sum system.img
   adb shell md5sum /external_sd/system.img
   ```
4. write disk image from terminal `dd`

   ```
   adb shell
   find /dev/block -name by-name
   ls -l /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system
   dd if=/external_sd/system.img of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system
   reboot recovery
   ```
5. disable dm-verity and recovery-from-boot.p (necessary for TWRP)

   ```
   adb disable-verity
   adb shell
   mount -w /system
   mv -v /system/recovery-from-boot.p /system/recovery-from-boot.bak
   ```

Comment: How can I do this in Windows?

Comment: Can you explain how can I do the whole process in Windows?

Comment: EVERYTHING in the above answer, most of the commands are to run in Linux environment when I Googled. Could you please give me a way how on doing these in Windows?

Comment: @alexcs 
I tried those before too. It shows downloading in MINGW64 but it never shows whether the download succeeded or not. And I have no idea about how can I find the downloaded file. Please understand how a person who has never used Linux feels like executing your commands and translating those to Windows environment.

Comment: I am sorry with the resources I have moving to Linux is not an option for me.

Comment: @alexcs Even though I have a flash drive, configuring Linux on it and getting to know the commands to get this done on it is a hassle for me at the moment. There can be  a lot of issues as in other app configurations which should be done as I do not have used Linux before.

Comment: @alexcs chathura@chathura-VirtualBox:~/Android$ simg2img system.sparse.img system.img
error: file_write: write: No space left on device
Cannot write output file This error message shows up. What can I do?

Comment: Note: **step 5** is probably most important to avoid losing TWRP (as the file name reveals *system* will overwrite *recovery from boot* otherwise). dm-verity can disabled by installing Magisk (rename apk to zip) or by installing [no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902)

Comment: @alexcs I tried with the live usb, I selected the Windows hard disk, Now i get below error.

"open your windows hard drive, right mouse click, "open terminal here""
 
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.39 80

Comment: @alexcs Last attempt was made in a live iso. Can this be a reason like the OS doesn't have access right to read or write anything to my C drive as it is the only drive that I have in my PC.