# how to convert Samsung sm-g531f firmware file to bootable image?

Tags: samsung, device-firmware

Recently I got deleted my OS in my SM-G531F. I found the rooted firmware online and I am trying to make a bootable image using the downloaded firmware. In my phone the the volume up key is not working, downloading and installing using the Odin tool is not an option. Can anyone guide me how to create a bootable USB so I can mount using an OTG and install the OS. I am using Windows OS in my desktop.

Comment: You could try to boot a recovery ROM via fastboot but I am not sure if this also works on your device as it is a Samsung. Direct booting from USB is not possible on Android the used botloader do not support this - Android is not a PC with an UEFI BIOS...

Comment: @Robert Any other solution which might work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install OS in Samsung smg531f which is without OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244994/how-to-install-os-in-samsung-smg531f-which-is-without-os)

Comment: you can boot into download mode from TWRP and flash with Odin